# DirectX 9 Image broken after device lost and IDIRECT3DDEVICE9::Reset

Tags: directx, directx-9

I'm practicing DirectX 9 recently, and an error occured when I pressed ALT+TAB to test if the handle on device lost works correctly.
This is how the pyramid normally looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3qfr.png

and after the reset function, it became all black, and some faces won't display.

These are my codes:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-A7Ln7aLla6fnFINU1WRUtlU1ViWUZ1UG93N09HU05NUnR4OEtYc2R5M2lhWC1YMExvNEk

Please help! I can't find any information on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you've forgotten to set your initially set render states at the device reset too. (Unfortunately the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't tell this explicitly or I overlooked it) At the device lost nearly all data (except managed ones, like your vertex/indexbuffers) is lost and you need to set all initial data again.

Your faces became black, because the lighting has been switched again to the default true.

Some faces will be vanish, because you cull mode has been reset.